# Is it possible to add a routing without moving all my application traffic to cloudflare?

Tags: cloudflare

I have very little knowledge on CloudFlare.

Currently all my application traffic goes through Akamai. what i am looking for is a way to create a new DNS at CloudFlare and route specific requests through CloudFlare.

For example if you configure the same in AWS CloudFront you can give an alternate name for the domain and use it instead of the origin urls and route specific traffic with specific rules.

but with CloudFlare the only way is to move all incoming traffic to CloudFlare as it is asking to replace the name servers with CloudFlare name servers.

i am looking for a way to create a new domain name or alternate domain name(similar to CloudFront) at CloudFlare and use it to route specific requests to my Akamai URLs based on page rules.

Is it possible to achieve??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you onboard a zone on Cloudflare, you can onboard it in FULL mode (Cloudflare becomes the authoritative DNS, by pointing the nameservers as you mention) or in **Partial/CNAME** mode (you retain an external authoritative DNS and point specific subdomains to Cloudflare). This could help you in separating which traffic goes through Cloudflare and what does not.

At the time of writing, The **Partial/CNAME onboarding** is available on **Business or Enterprise plans**. [Documentation is provided at this link](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020348832-Understanding-a-CNAME-Setup)

Another possibility could be to direct all the traffic to Cloudflare and then use the [Load Balancing](https://developers.cloudflare.com/load-balancing/) capability and [custom rules](https://developers.cloudflare.com/load-balancing/additional-options/load-balancing-rules) to route the traffic as required.